# Validation rule for the age gap field while editing or cloning

Tags: validation-rule

I have a below field, Age main, on a custom object " Quote", The " Main Driver" field is replicating from the account name ( personal account).

[image]

The age & other details also get replicate from the account, i.e here the age 23 is maintained in the account " Chimni", But the user have the flexibility to edit the age on the same page or while cloning the page to get a new quote. But i need to set a validation rule where , the user can set only one year gap from the maintained one ( i.e he can edit it as either 23 or 25), it should show validation error if its 22 or 27 etc. If you can help me out in setting. Thnx

I tried to write the below VR but its showing syntax error, and failing.

```
(Age_MainD__c) <> OR(PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)+1, PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)-1)

Alternatives :

Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)+1
OR Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your VR as :

```
AND(Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)+1,Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)-1)
```

Comment: Only issue, i m facing is while its showing the correct validation rule, certain created process builder flows errors showing, but nowhere the Age field is being used on those flows. But the ccount object has been used with other fields, Do you have idea why so, and how to avoid that. I need to have those PB workflows as well. Thnx

Comment: Though I did not get your question completely, I think you are leaving the age field as null, which is creating the error. Try changing your VR as:
AND(Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)+1,Age_MainD__c <> PRIORVALUE(Age_MainD__c)-1,Age_MainD__c <> null)

Comment: Hi Tharun, No its not null. I edited from the existing record. But while if its more than one year gap , its showing the VR error message but while its correct its not showing the VR error message but while saving its showing some flow error, while i deactivated the three flows i have created on teh account object with other fields, i am able to save properly. But as i need those flows as well on my custom object, if there would be any other way to achieve this particular need apart from apply the VR ? Thnx

Comment: The first time while i am creating the record on " custom Quote" object, its taking the Age field automaticallly from the account, so i dont think the issue is due to null.